# How to create temporary tables in SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables

I am trying to create a temporary table in SQL Server from another table for example in Redshift I do the following

```
Create temporay table CARS as (
SELECT *
FROM BD_CARS_111
);

SELECT *
FROM CARS;
```

Is there a similar statement in SQL SERVER?

Comment: `CREATE TABLE #Cars`. SQL Server doesn't have a special statement, instead it has [special names](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql#temporary-tables).

Answer (score 7):

You can create temporary tables by prefixing the table name with # or ##. Single # temporary tables are specific to the connection and session (aka who created it). Double ## temporary tables global and can be seen and used by other connections too. The latter goes away when all the connections using it are closed.

As per your example, in MS SQL Server it would be:

```
SELECT *
into #Cars
FROM BD_CARS_111;

SELECT * FROM #CARS;
```

Comment: Thank you. I was able to create a temporary table from a select example:
`code`
SELECT *
into #Cars
FROM (SELECT * FROM BD_CARS_111) BD_C; `code`

Comment: @dapdap, you don't need to write redundant code. It is sufficient to write as I did in the sample above. IOW: SELECT * into #Cars FROM BD_CARS_111;

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    product_name,
    list_price
INTO #trek_products --- temporary table
FROM
    production.products
WHERE
    brand_id = 9;
```

Comment: SQL Server provided two ways to create temporary tables via SELECT INTO and CREATE TABLE statements.

Comment: The second way to create a temporary table is to use the CREATE TABLE 
 
CREATE TABLE #haro_products (
    product_name VARCHAR(MAX),
    list_price DEC(10,2)
);

Comment: It would have been better if you had edited your answer rather than provided explanatory comments.